# Flutter desktop application freeze after one interaction

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to learn Flutter and in order to do so I am building a small desktop application.

I am planning to use an rich text editor  as a part of the application. After a lot of research I settled [appflowy_editor](https://github.com/AppFlowy-IO/appflowy-editor). The original code had a [one line bug](https://github.com/AppFlowy-IO/appflowy-editor/pull/686/files) that they have a PR for, but for my case  I just forked the repo, fixed it myself, and then used my forked git repo in pubspec.yaml. And then I can run the example code completely fine. However, when I try to follow the example code (specifically the home_page.dart) and integrate it with my code it does not work as expected.

In the example, everything is okay, in my case when I click on one item from a list view and then retrieve the underlying content and then try to display it in the editor then the whole application freezes. I do not have any idea why. The skeleton of my app was generated following an [official codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-animated-responsive-layout#0)

Here is the code where I am trying to integrate it. The import `import 'editor.dart';` is the exact same file as in the example.

And now the full code

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:appflowy_editor/appflowy_editor.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import '../models/model.dart' as model;
import '../models/data.dart' as data;
import 'document_list_view.dart';
import 'disappearing_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'disappearing_navigation_rail.dart';
import 'add_menu_button.dart';
import 'editor.dart';

class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  const Feed({super.key});

  @override
  State<Feed> createState() => _FeedState();
}

class _FeedState extends State<Feed> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  int selectedIndex = 0;
  bool wideScreen = false;

  model.Document? selectedDocument;
  late WidgetBuilder _widgetBuilder;
  late EditorState _editorState;
  late Future<String> _jsonString;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    model.Document d = model.Document(
        id: Uuid().v4(),
        content: "",
        createTime: DateTime.now(),
        summary: "",
        tags: [data.tag0]);

    _jsonString = d.toAppFlowyJson();

    _widgetBuilder = (context) => Editor(
          jsonString: _jsonString,
          onEditorStateChange: (editorState) {
            _editorState = editorState;
          },
        );
    // _loadEditor(context, _jsonString);
  }

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();

    _widgetBuilder = (context) => Editor(
          jsonString: _jsonString,
          onEditorStateChange: (editorState) {
            _editorState = editorState;
            _jsonString = Future.value(
              jsonEncode(_editorState.document.toJson()),
            );
          },
        );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    wideScreen = width > 600;
  }

  void _onDocumentSelected(BuildContext context, int documentIndex) {
    setState(() {
      selectedDocument = data.documents[documentIndex];
      // Update the jsonString with the selected document's content
      final jsonString = selectedDocument!.toAppFlowyJson();
      // Update the editor state
      _loadEditor(context, jsonString);
    });
  }

  Widget _getContentForSelectedIndex() {
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        return DocumentListView(
          onSelected: (index) => _onDocumentSelected(context, index),
        );
      // Add other cases for different indexes
      default:
        return const Text('Selected view not implemented yet');
    }
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return _widgetBuilder(context);
  }

  Future<void> _loadEditor(
    BuildContext context,
    Future<String> jsonString, {
    TextDirection textDirection = TextDirection.ltr,
  }) async {
    final completer = Completer<void>();
    setState(
      () {
        _widgetBuilder = (context) => Editor(
              jsonString: jsonString,
              onEditorStateChange: (editorState) {
                _editorState = editorState;
              },
              textDirection: textDirection,
            );
      },
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme _colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final Color _backgroundColor = Color.alphaBlend(
        _colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.14), _colorScheme.surface);

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Row(
        children: [
          if (wideScreen)
            DisappearingNavigationRail(
              selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
              backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
              onDestinationSelected: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: _backgroundColor,
              child: _getContentForSelectedIndex(),
            ),
          ),
          if (selectedDocument != null && wideScreen)
            Expanded(child: _buildBody(context)),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: wideScreen ? null : const AddMenuButton(),
      bottomNavigationBar: wideScreen
          ? null
          : DisappearingBottomNavigationBar(
              selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
              onDestinationSelected: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}

extension on model.Document {
  Future<String> toAppFlowyJson() {
    return Future<String>.value(jsonEncode({
      "document": {
        "type": "page",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "data": {
              "delta": [
                {
                  "insert": '${this.content}\n',
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

With my minimal knowledge I can not understand what is wrong. When I click on the list view, I can fetch the content and then I can see that the content in the editor right of the list view, but as soon as that is shown the entire application becomes unresponsive.

Any lead is welcome. Thanks in advance. (My OS is Ubuntu 22.04).